# I am getting handshake_failure while calling https URL in my program

Tags: java, https

Please see the complete logs

```
trustStore is: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=m3_external_ca_test
  Issuer:  CN=m3_external_ca_test
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Tue Jun 12 01:57:02 IST 2018 until Fri Jun 09 01:57:02 IST 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=ecw-test.mtn.co.ug, C=UG
  Issuer:  CN=m3_external_ca_test
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x-2afddf7d2f077bc9
  Valid from Tue Jun 12 13:21:39 IST 2018 until Thu Jun 11 13:21:39 IST 2020

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=rchhabra@xpwallet.com, CN=test.xpwallet.com, OU=ARED, O=ARED, L=RW, ST=RW, C=RW
  Issuer:  CN=m3_external_ca_test
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xb165b0b05e8fed1
  Valid from Mon Sep 09 13:58:16 IST 2019 until Wed Sep 08 13:58:16 IST 2021

keyStore is : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1553995999 bytes = { 68, 80, 88, 59, 21, 219, 212, 92, 98, 185, 156, 181, 51, 80, 35, 252, 156, 223, 223, 151, 72, 252, 100, 85, 35, 44, 134, 21 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=ecw-test.mtn.co.ug]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 236
                             .......
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 87
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 777089106 bytes = { 227, 20, 28, 76, 116, 217, 88, 149, 150, 110, 124, 147, 131, 74, 87, 141, 20, 91, 165, 22, 59, 250, 90, 47, 77, 228, 194, 218 }
Session ID:  {170, 0, 108, 219, 127, 197, 96, 63, 147, 200, 99, 209, 231, 13, 8, 199, 114, 107, 230, 143, 75, 52, 149, 43, 141, 126, 68, 174, 182, 157, 88, 215}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 87
0000: 02 00 00 53 03 03 2E 51   70 52 E3 14 1C 4C 74 D9  ...S...QpR...Lt.
0010: 58 95 96 6E 7C 93 83 4A   57 8D 14 5B A5 16 3B FA  X..n...JW..[..;.
0020: 5A 2F 4D E4 C2 DA 20 AA   00 6C DB 7F C5 60 3F 93  Z/M... ..l...`?.
0030: C8 63 D1 E7 0D 08 C7 72   6B E6 8F 4B 34 95 2B 8D  .c.....rk..K4.+.
0040: 7E 44 AE B6 9D 58 D7 C0   30 00 00 0B FF 01 00 01  .D...X..0.......
0050: 00 00 0B 00 02 01 00                               .......
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 03 09 33                                     ....3
[Raw read]: length = 2355
0000: 0B 00 09 2F 00 09 2C 00   04 1B 30 82 04 17 30 82  .../..,...0...0.
0010: 01 FF A0 03 02 01 02 02   08 D5 02 20 82 D0 F8 84  ........... ....
0020: 37 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48   86 F7 0D 01 01 0B 05 00  70...*.H........
0030: 30 1E 31 1C 30 1A 06 03   55 04 03 0C 13 6D 33 5F  0.1.0...U....m3_
0040: 65 78 74 65 72 6E 61 6C   5F 63 61 5F 74 65 73 74  external_ca_test
0050: 30 1E 17 0D 31 38 30 36   31 32 30 37 35 31 33 39  0...180612075139
0060: 5A 17 0D 32 30 30 36 31   31 30 37 35 31 33 39 5A  Z..200611075139Z
0070: 30 2A 31 0B 30 09 06 03   55 04 06 13 02 55 47 31  0*1.0...U....UG1
0080: 1B 30 19 06 03 55 04 03   0C 12 65 63 77 2D 74 65  .0...U....ecw-te
0090: 73 74 2E 6D 74 6E 2E 63   6F 2E 75 67 30 82 01 22  st.mtn.co.ug0.."
00A0: 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86   F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03  0...*.H.........
00B0: 82 01 0F 00 30 82 01 0A   02 82 01 01 00 94 9B F1  ....0...........
00C0: 04 82 3F B0 F9 AE F4 98   CD 53 E4 1B B8 9A 90 A7  ..?......S......
00D0: 54 C2 5B BD 2E 68 40 DC   1C 4A 15 FC 8A A9 3C 37  T.[..h@..J....<7
00E0: EE 9F 4C C7 68 32 B5 5B   61 07 6A E1 F6 D3 17 E5  ..L.h2.[a.j.....
00F0: FC 3B 30 76 E2 5C 91 4C   91 46 0A 44 AC 3B 0E A5  .;0v.\.L.F.D.;..
0100: 3E 0E FB E8 15 62 13 AA   11 DC 40 25 FC 2D B1 5B  >....b....@%.-.[
0110: 6B 17 F2 0F 4E B6 3A B1   52 74 88 08 40 B7 43 0C  k...N.:.Rt..@.C.
0120: 55 5C 5B A6 8D 8E 45 87   6E D0 B7 50 20 AD 39 10  U\[...E.n..P .9.
0130: 74 C1 3A C0 B9 72 2E D7   D3 EE FF 46 DE EB E6 E1  t.:..r.....F....
0140: 88 43 C4 4F 73 11 33 93   34 CE F4 C2 A8 66 FC F4  .C.Os.3.4....f..
0150: E3 7B 5B 43 71 0C 6C 26   5C F5 47 B3 CE 8F FA 14  ..[Cq.l&\.G.....
0160: 02 7D D3 24 31 A1 13 7A   81 D6 DE D0 83 16 80 93  ...$1..z........
0170: 5A 7E 75 D6 02 B4 04 F3   35 51 88 CC 36 CE 43 79  Z.u.....5Q..6.Cy
0180: F5 F8 9D 01 74 9E 81 80   78 96 2A 25 BF 02 B0 3E  ....t...x.*%...>
0190: AD EC 3C 63 72 86 17 A5   C2 35 04 72 2F 94 77 D6  ..<cr....5.r/.w.
01A0: 92 7E A5 9C 21 19 97 0F   80 EB C2 6E 50 92 9C 33  ....!......nP..3
01B0: B0 30 FA CE C9 B2 4F E9   E5 3F 67 F8 ED 02 03 01  .0....O..?g.....
01C0: 00 01 A3 4D 30 4B 30 09   06 03 55 1D 13 04 02 30  ...M0K0...U....0
01D0: 00 30 1D 06 03 55 1D 0E   04 16 04 14 07 DE 5D 71  .0...U........]q
01E0: F6 5C F7 0C 36 49 0F 0D   42 B7 32 DE 98 6C 74 BF  .\..6I..B.2..lt.
01F0: 30 1F 06 03 55 1D 23 04   18 30 16 80 14 5F 7F 19  0...U.#..0..._..
0200: 08 87 CD CC DD 56 B8 E4   C5 F4 6D B3 8E 18 E6 E3  .....V....m.....
0210: 83 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48   86 F7 0D 01 01 0B 05 00  .0...*.H........
0220: 03 82 02 01 00 48 E7 EC   53 40 38 F2 CA 62 39 A1  .....H..S@8..b9.
0230: 5B B5 21 3E 67 F6 0E 7F   28 1A 71 21 A1 4B 24 4F  [.!>g...(.q!.K$O
0240: 68 39 4D E5 48 4B 76 2A   78 B0 4C 66 C3 93 37 10  h9M.HKv*x.Lf..7.
0250: 40 42 A7 55 15 A6 4B 6A   0A A0 F4 0F 66 55 96 7F  @B.U..Kj....fU..
0260: 45 DD C5 D7 6D 1A 9D D9   26 A7 04 C1 A3 B8 59 48  E...m...&.....YH
0270: 9A CE D6 50 ED EC 48 7B   16 9D 9C EF 43 E2 E8 3E  ...P..H.....C..>
0280: 5D 46 B7 A8 5B A1 D0 1A   71 2B 30 68 7F 2C 6F 31  ]F..[...q+0h.,o1
0290: A2 D9 A5 4E 16 09 3D 5E   F1 F7 A1 29 6E E9 37 61  ...N..=^...)n.7a
02A0: 22 15 44 CE 34 CC AB 82   7D 1E 53 41 6E 52 9E A0  ".D.4.....SAnR..
02B0: 0B D3 50 32 70 5A 42 F5   FC F1 67 D3 3B A4 93 10  ..P2pZB...g.;...
02C0: 34 FB C0 F8 70 2D 90 2B   97 4C E5 0B 15 FA F0 45  4...p-.+.L.....E
02D0: 3E B6 52 06 7D E0 9E E1   09 CD 42 33 0F 80 71 DA  >.R.......B3..q.
02E0: D5 44 19 60 81 C0 B9 32   7B 4A 78 67 7E 1F 65 33  .D.`...2.Jxg..e3
02F0: 60 B2 B2 4D EF 19 87 B8   AD FE D2 5E 76 63 9E 73  `..M.......^vc.s
0300: 66 B0 B2 41 AD 1D E8 E0   3F 99 DC D0 D2 C7 75 7A  f..A....?.....uz
0310: 74 6E 9E 83 0B BF 8F 91   37 A0 E3 62 F9 E0 69 9C  tn......7..b..i.
0320: FE 95 9C B4 13 67 A5 32   C0 5A 97 5C B5 7F 36 9E  .....g.2.Z.\..6.
0330: 83 F3 E2 82 BD F8 F7 68   0F 75 EE 48 9F B4 C5 E2  .......h.u.H....
0340: EA 91 59 2C 96 70 DE F9   43 F7 B0 8F C9 C4 8E 24  ..Y,.p..C......$
0350: CE AD 73 40 0F 38 70 CE   4A 45 01 93 2E FB D1 BF  ..s@.8p.JE......
0360: 1A 4E 65 66 FE E7 67 26   70 B6 A0 B4 97 67 2F 91  .Nef..g&p....g/.
0370: 27 6D CF 9A 32 BA E9 C4   CB 1C 13 67 D3 18 40 89  'm..2......g..@.
0380: CF C5 E4 A4 86 A1 5F E7   C3 85 7A 4E 3B 57 AD 95  ......_...zN;W..
0390: FB B0 73 8D 91 19 26 3B   BD C2 CD EF 39 51 9E C6  ..s...&;....9Q..
03A0: 14 73 0A 6F 5C 73 70 0B   73 04 A3 CF D2 34 AC 3A  .s.o\sp.s....4.:
03B0: 43 06 8F AF F5 37 B9 1A   33 A9 D0 CF EF 14 60 29  C....7..3.....`)
03C0: 12 71 92 74 25 D9 3C B3   C6 5D B7 10 96 13 0D FA  .q.t%.<..]......
03D0: 31 42 13 AC B2 ED 50 03   CF E8 6B 28 5F 88 F7 57  1B....P...k(_..W
03E0: 1E CC 47 B8 EB EC B9 E0   BA FF 09 24 F7 A1 03 43  ..G........$...C
03F0: 2A C8 75 14 C4 B6 31 A2   2C 3F 5A D3 FC E6 09 87  *.u...1.,?Z.....
0400: 55 AC DF 06 B7 72 EF 3C   A6 2B 20 9E 06 F7 B6 53  U....r.<.+ ....S
0410: 0E 8B F1 C3 4F 38 72 15   BC 27 14 06 27 79 AF AA  ....O8r..'..'y..
0420: 3C FA 47 B4 2C 00 05 0B   30 82 05 07 30 82 02 EF  <.G.,...0...0...
0430: A0 03 02 01 02 02 01 01   30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86  ........0...*.H.
0440: F7 0D 01 01 0B 05 00 30   1E 31 1C 30 1A 06 03 55  .......0.1.0...U
0450: 04 03 0C 13 6D 33 5F 65   78 74 65 72 6E 61 6C 5F  ....m3_external_
0460: 63 61 5F 74 65 73 74 30   1E 17 0D 31 38 30 36 31  ca_test0...18061
0470: 31 32 30 32 37 30 32 5A   17 0D 32 38 30 36 30 38  1202702Z..280608
0480: 32 30 32 37 30 32 5A 30   1E 31 1C 30 1A 06 03 55  202702Z0.1.0...U
0490: 04 03 0C 13 6D 33 5F 65   78 74 65 72 6E 61 6C 5F  ....m3_external_
04A0: 63 61 5F 74 65 73 74 30   82 02 22 30 0D 06 09 2A  ca_test0.."0...*
04B0: 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01   05 00 03 82 02 0F 00 30  .H.............0
04C0: 82 02 0A 02 82 02 01 00   88 91 97 01 35 BB 35 3D  ............5.5=
04D0: 2C 06 7D 2A 6D 8A 36 26   65 18 08 8D 46 EB B1 0E  ,..*m.6&e...F...
04E0: 92 09 53 79 CF 63 36 57   CA 67 B8 B5 60 1C FF D6  ..Sy.c6W.g..`...
04F0: C3 E8 9D 27 9B 04 DF 7F   B5 D2 A3 67 43 C9 85 2B  ...'.......gC..+
0500: 60 CB 94 5C D6 EF 19 75   FA 32 53 A3 C4 FF 4A 5E  `..\...u.2S...J^
0510: 6E 99 50 97 5E 5C 57 0A   C2 68 A5 16 0C 06 09 40  n.P.^\W..h.....@
0520: 8B 20 3F 3B CB C2 B8 09   FE D4 3D 5B 49 DA EB 7E  . ?;......=[I...
0530: A0 2E 65 41 0A BD 89 13   F9 63 49 C7 AE 2B 07 1C  ..eA.....cI..+..
0540: 59 85 22 09 7C 9D 31 9B   6E FB 33 6E 4A CF 45 03  Y."...1.n.3nJ.E.
0550: 55 A8 6F 6F AC 3A 4A 3B   00 95 C1 65 B5 56 6F 6F  U.oo.:J;...e.Voo
0560: F5 9E 23 6C 8A 0D 14 DA   36 18 C3 7D 6F 88 4A B7  ..#l....6...o.J.
0570: 99 79 81 9C F0 F3 97 AB   32 24 95 AC FF BA 75 3F  .y......2$....u?
0580: 47 75 22 91 3E 23 20 D8   DF F6 BF F2 F4 B9 E0 AB  Gu".># .........
0590: E9 84 51 90 4F 96 48 21   DC BE 74 50 7B 78 4E 77  ..Q.O.H!..tP.xNw
05A0: 4C 45 9B 8C 7B 05 B9 C4   76 0D 40 2C CD 59 3B 65  LE......v.@,.Y;e
05B0: BE FD DB BF 88 D3 02 0A   E3 AA 5E ED 1E 03 00 74  ..........^....t
05C0: 98 B4 7C B7 D8 DE C6 0D   38 7B A7 98 C6 02 7C FF  ........8.......
05D0: 91 BD DC E2 F0 25 1F 62   58 E3 80 7F AE 8C 9B 97  .....%.bX.......
05E0: 40 97 C0 2D 6E 02 14 4D   B9 B2 EC 47 01 D2 48 56  @..-n..M...G..HV
05F0: 94 38 E3 4D 75 B3 7B 96   11 AC E3 EF EC DF D1 4F  .8.Mu..........O
0600: 84 28 0C 67 5F C0 D8 A8   68 B2 BE 8A D3 63 AD 2D  .(.g_...h....c.-
0610: A9 0A 62 4B 73 E4 EC CE   3C FD 8D 3F 5C 18 00 CD  ..bKs...<..?\...
0620: A2 66 F5 3F 75 AC ED 31   20 F0 6A C6 5B 88 D2 33  .f.?u..1 .j.[..3
0630: 7B 73 CD 69 CC E3 4B 1D   9C 3B 83 5A 3E 95 7C 19  .s.i..K..;.Z>...
0640: 46 EE 34 0B 73 7E 7E F7   1F 32 DC F4 08 E7 51 3B  F.4.s....2....Q;
0650: 40 B3 F2 35 26 06 8E E5   57 D0 8E 25 F8 A3 B2 9C  @..5&...W..%....
0660: 4A 57 4A 88 D1 B1 50 1C   F1 A1 E4 19 C8 FF 6E 22  JWJ...P.......n"
0670: D9 BC 63 D0 8F 32 6E 02   0A 5A 6F 2B D8 68 40 A3  ..c..2n..Zo+.h@.
0680: B6 65 2A 7A 42 D6 03 39   46 BE 8E 2E 58 E8 D8 7B  .e*zB..9F...X...
0690: A2 FF 9E BD A4 B7 3A 4C   E1 C2 11 35 A8 E0 C8 07  ......:L...5....
06A0: 21 DE 34 7D A7 72 5D 6D   A3 7F B5 F7 E3 61 8E 09  !.4..r]m.....a..
06B0: D9 03 E1 AB 17 CE 8F 83   2F 22 F0 3B F4 93 EA 43  ......../".;...C
06C0: A6 C9 10 72 9E 32 CB E3   02 03 01 00 01 A3 50 30  ...r.2........P0
06D0: 4E 30 0C 06 03 55 1D 13   04 05 30 03 01 01 FF 30  N0...U....0....0
06E0: 1D 06 03 55 1D 0E 04 16   04 14 5F 7F 19 08 87 CD  ...U......_.....
06F0: CC DD 56 B8 E4 C5 F4 6D   B3 8E 18 E6 E3 83 30 1F  ..V....m......0.
0700: 06 03 55 1D 23 04 18 30   16 80 14 5F 7F 19 08 87  ..U.#..0..._....
0710: CD CC DD 56 B8 E4 C5 F4   6D B3 8E 18 E6 E3 83 30  ...V....m......0
0720: 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7   0D 01 01 0B 05 00 03 82  ...*.H..........
0730: 02 01 00 2B A6 71 B1 E3   8A AF 97 CF 02 55 D6 EC  ...+.q.......U..
0740: 02 CE 56 69 27 B5 34 51   33 19 74 18 DF F4 1C A2  ..Vi'.4Q3.t.....
0750: 63 7A DB B6 0B 3A 00 1F   64 13 DA B6 73 5F BC BD  cz...:..d...s_..
0760: 69 BA 08 7B 7E 15 CE A5   8F 85 0F 35 EF CE 46 A5  i..........5..F.
0770: 46 77 B0 CB 86 22 4C CA   EA F1 28 B8 94 E6 B3 6C  Fw..."L...(....l
0780: 42 61 36 66 34 6C FD 87   4E 2E BA EA 33 5D 14 DD  Ba6f4l..N...3]..
0790: 84 1F 4B 89 EF 1B AE D9   F3 38 3E DF 8A 73 00 C5  ..K......8>..s..
07A0: 12 86 D2 95 00 BC 5D FC   EB AA F2 8D 24 6C D5 70  ......].....$l.p
07B0: 0E 86 B0 A7 CC EE 29 8D   6F BB B6 20 CA 78 5E 5C  ......).o.. .x^\
07C0: 2E 8A 64 32 AA E1 DF 1F   8A E3 F3 BE 73 35 70 B8  ..d2........s5p.
07D0: 75 E0 77 BB 9C 9A 6D C8   2D 5F 65 23 DD E3 F7 64  u.w...m.-_e#...d
07E0: 89 F4 C4 D3 60 2B 24 F1   C2 C5 DF 88 01 90 F5 68  ....`+$........h
07F0: 67 9D 4B 47 C7 5F 9F 9B   2F E6 71 3F AE F3 A5 72  g.KG._../.q?...r
0800: 78 8D 73 8B 77 0D 21 C3   A4 B0 D3 B2 F3 02 68 AC  x.s.w.!.......h.
0810: 66 31 83 85 3B 98 0F F7   8B 5C 33 4B 06 4E 08 43  f1..;....\3K.N.C
0820: 58 CF 74 1B 0A B9 F4 BF   5D 71 D9 18 30 AF 66 B7  X.t.....]q..0.f.
0830: D8 8A 43 0F 0C 6A 12 D2   8A 0E 0D 87 15 77 70 D0  ..C..j.......wp.
0840: AC D6 89 11 43 27 56 5B   02 E0 11 43 FF EF 1A DC  ....C'V[...C....
0850: 62 F5 8E 0F E5 76 FD D9   13 03 40 47 C3 79 B0 B9  b....v....@G.y..
0860: 3B 7C EA 2F 94 93 CD 35   D3 D4 35 7E 5C 5B 01 41  ;../...5..5.\[.A
0870: BB 59 8F 85 A4 04 61 09   C8 13 4A 54 FB 66 CE 2D  .Y....a...JT.f.-
0880: 2C 55 F7 E6 58 EF 06 30   1D 49 78 FE 89 DB 01 12  ,U..X..0.Ix.....
0890: 40 CA EA 9A 5B 02 98 21   83 92 09 09 9A 33 4C C7  @...[..!.....3L.
08A0: FC 83 9A 74 FB 79 0E CD   4C 09 66 0F B5 3E D5 BB  ...t.y..L.f..>..
08B0: E5 6B 6D E4 9D EC 13 F8   5E D3 5A 88 1E 41 82 55  .km.....^.Z..A.U
08C0: F2 EC 54 1D 86 22 3F D8   7A CF 37 63 9F 96 D2 29  ..T.."?.z.7c...)
08D0: 97 86 CD 15 02 4D EF 9A   24 3E 42 FC 8D C7 32 3F  .....M..$>B...2?
08E0: 0B 8A 0B 7D AC F4 8A A5   25 86 7C C2 76 EC 36 10  ........%...v.6.
08F0: A5 0B 65 F4 4C 8B 25 2A   CE EF 44 8A E8 7D 26 CD  ..e.L.%*..D...&.
0900: 45 01 4C 4A 21 D0 FF 87   4F 6E E9 72 3A AE E5 80  E.LJ!...On.r:...
0910: 3F B3 67 87 AE BE D5 BA   44 21 21 82 CF 71 AF 1E  ?.g.....D!!..q..
0920: AD B3 CF A7 A2 7E 47 F7   A5 E1 4D 8B F3 3B FB 2B  ......G...M..;.+
0930: 3A 54 94                                           :T.
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 2355
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=ecw-test.mtn.co.ug, C=UG
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 18760166742336210646007664495745031327190029464821669470306527829763575346528631782132547941171360849683772583992605930917301481441101416645698614632353739542027025964353638587080188542222265595135606550050263251566024846748496906202147541040537923796925027183659957438551757027649843448864636566620125718160161036066401938675839562124067154220020711797081648913760388845438273214664283001626409771418011670171258850910841909886694279369529607357694509457161786296272001851016465260784571102998268482752579716916942479394342018541725225860288291413277309136676355212252408510983833354048707941547165862153808461166829
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Jun 12 13:21:39 IST 2018,
               To: Thu Jun 11 13:21:39 IST 2020]
  Issuer: CN=m3_external_ca_test
  SerialNumber: [   -2afddf7d 2f077bc9]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 5F 7F 19 08 87 CD CC DD   56 B8 E4 C5 F4 6D B3 8E  _.......V....m..
0010: 18 E6 E3 83                                        ....
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 07 DE 5D 71 F6 5C F7 0C   36 49 0F 0D 42 B7 32 DE  ..]q.\..6I..B.2.
0010: 98 6C 74 BF                                        .lt.
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 48 E7 EC 53 40 38 F2 CA   62 39 A1 5B B5 21 3E 67  H..S@8..b9.[.!>g
0010: F6 0E 7F 28 1A 71 21 A1   4B 24 4F 68 39 4D E5 48  ...(.q!.K$Oh9M.H
0020: 4B 76 2A 78 B0 4C 66 C3   93 37 10 40 42 A7 55 15  Kv*x.Lf..7.@B.U.
0030: A6 4B 6A 0A A0 F4 0F 66   55 96 7F 45 DD C5 D7 6D  .Kj....fU..E...m
0040: 1A 9D D9 26 A7 04 C1 A3   B8 59 48 9A CE D6 50 ED  ...&.....YH...P.
0050: EC 48 7B 16 9D 9C EF 43   E2 E8 3E 5D 46 B7 A8 5B  .H.....C..>]F..[
0060: A1 D0 1A 71 2B 30 68 7F   2C 6F 31 A2 D9 A5 4E 16  ...q+0h.,o1...N.
0070: 09 3D 5E F1 F7 A1 29 6E   E9 37 61 22 15 44 CE 34  .=^...)n.7a".D.4
0080: CC AB 82 7D 1E 53 41 6E   52 9E A0 0B D3 50 32 70  .....SAnR....P2p
0090: 5A 42 F5 FC F1 67 D3 3B   A4 93 10 34 FB C0 F8 70  ZB...g.;...4...p
00A0: 2D 90 2B 97 4C E5 0B 15   FA F0 45 3E B6 52 06 7D  -.+.L.....E>.R..
00B0: E0 9E E1 09 CD 42 33 0F   80 71 DA D5 44 19 60 81  .....B3..q..D.`.
00C0: C0 B9 32 7B 4A 78 67 7E   1F 65 33 60 B2 B2 4D EF  ..2.Jxg..e3`..M.
00D0: 19 87 B8 AD FE D2 5E 76   63 9E 73 66 B0 B2 41 AD  ......^vc.sf..A.
00E0: 1D E8 E0 3F 99 DC D0 D2   C7 75 7A 74 6E 9E 83 0B  ...?.....uztn...
00F0: BF 8F 91 37 A0 E3 62 F9   E0 69 9C FE 95 9C B4 13  ...7..b..i......
0100: 67 A5 32 C0 5A 97 5C B5   7F 36 9E 83 F3 E2 82 BD  g.2.Z.\..6......
0110: F8 F7 68 0F 75 EE 48 9F   B4 C5 E2 EA 91 59 2C 96  ..h.u.H......Y,.
0120: 70 DE F9 43 F7 B0 8F C9   C4 8E 24 CE AD 73 40 0F  p..C......$..s@.
0130: 38 70 CE 4A 45 01 93 2E   FB D1 BF 1A 4E 65 66 FE  8p.JE.......Nef.
0140: E7 67 26 70 B6 A0 B4 97   67 2F 91 27 6D CF 9A 32  .g&p....g/.'m..2
0150: BA E9 C4 CB 1C 13 67 D3   18 40 89 CF C5 E4 A4 86  ......g..@......
0160: A1 5F E7 C3 85 7A 4E 3B   57 AD 95 FB B0 73 8D 91  ._...zN;W....s..
0170: 19 26 3B BD C2 CD EF 39   51 9E C6 14 73 0A 6F 5C  .&;....9Q...s.o\
0180: 73 70 0B 73 04 A3 CF D2   34 AC 3A 43 06 8F AF F5  sp.s....4.:C....
0190: 37 B9 1A 33 A9 D0 CF EF   14 60 29 12 71 92 74 25  7..3.....`).q.t%
01A0: D9 3C B3 C6 5D B7 10 96   13 0D FA 31 42 13 AC B2  .<..]......1B...
01B0: ED 50 03 CF E8 6B 28 5F   88 F7 57 1E CC 47 B8 EB  .P...k(_..W..G..
01C0: EC B9 E0 BA FF 09 24 F7   A1 03 43 2A C8 75 14 C4  ......$...C*.u..
01D0: B6 31 A2 2C 3F 5A D3 FC   E6 09 87 55 AC DF 06 B7  .1.,?Z.....U....
01E0: 72 EF 3C A6 2B 20 9E 06   F7 B6 53 0E 8B F1 C3 4F  r.<.+ ....S....O
01F0: 38 72 15 BC 27 14 06 27   79 AF AA 3C FA 47 B4 2C  8r..'..'y..<.G.,

]
chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=m3_external_ca_test
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 4096 bits
  modulus: 557151729257513438839644150388994050633257463150916756666288129639829273703829321229726135597409651267923163753540191812166215491681418750095800124039177047610921338095584777847693211532173924379229429356988539203692954447396372998918466327209925104754132112452040117309037337899793627958986425102119033235946821927766586736238366399909058576730416643277317107012215518939823367870794050831329502931200465236622573918783105404625612091949806908192432139109240293637102989990682880462249168023520927635743443446087921283697496893345488202662761882381308627361840750432546788878561709613460624082025467787953553336217008221683384807014080736684293664958483129172471210065490491426284163056269241358166314722428304811418521683643082368229159063698592514583819017847444753883136339509772465286214624964332968123898190861074330815047931167787772472284663941700641329596402280513951974416355486973105161800167081754916542965323709213497146993492567648900054926942904129100128883337830188142220064431633066248767423041608386155063786967752130358976047264442038254969571760619157207175872513536937111013216384389085422556190661912889530860668679008606571201626257041618168321149461375656917730604989009634813014849328401907226383781886872547
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Jun 12 01:57:02 IST 2018,
               To: Fri Jun 09 01:57:02 IST 2028]
  Issuer: CN=m3_external_ca_test
  SerialNumber: [    01]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 5F 7F 19 08 87 CD CC DD   56 B8 E4 C5 F4 6D B3 8E  _.......V....m..
0010: 18 E6 E3 83                                        ....
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 5F 7F 19 08 87 CD CC DD   56 B8 E4 C5 F4 6D B3 8E  _.......V....m..
0010: 18 E6 E3 83                                        ....
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:

***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=ecw-test.mtn.co.ug, C=UG
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 18760166742336210646007664495745031327190029464821669470306527829763575346528631782132547941171360849683772583992605930917301481441101416645698614632353739542027025964353638587080188542222265595135606550050263251566024846748496906202147541040537923796925027183659957438551757027649843448864636566620125718160161036066401938675839562124067154220020711797081648913760388845438273214664283001626409771418011670171258850910841909886694279369529607357694509457161786296272001851016465260784571102998268482752579716916942479394342018541725225860288291413277309136676355212252408510983833354048707941547165862153808461166829
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Jun 12 13:21:39 IST 2018,
               To: Thu Jun 11 13:21:39 IST 2020]
  Issuer: CN=m3_external_ca_test
  SerialNumber: [   -2afddf7d 2f077bc9]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 5F 7F 19 08 87 CD CC DD   56 B8 E4 C5 F4 6D B3 8E  _.......V....m..
0010: 18 E6 E3 83                                        ....
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 07 DE 5D 71 F6 5C F7 0C   36 49 0F 0D 42 B7 32 DE  ..]q.\..6I..B.2.
0010: 98 6C 74 BF                                        .lt.
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:

main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 333
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 22767616842921672428296979524517536574453051884265921346618822148174980533140
  public y coord: 91036568456536708035496750224567632902507611421192548364369040295164559077412
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)

main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 70
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2), SHA512withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=m3_external_ca_test>
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 70

0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange

[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.common.Utils.sendPostRequest(Utils.java:122)
    at com.common.Utils.execute(Utils.java:77)
    at com.common.Utils.main(Utils.java:158)
```

Comment: can you share https calling code?

Comment: HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

     GetMethod method = new GetMethod();
     method.setPath(url);

     int statusCode = httpclient.executeMethod(method);
     System.out.println("Status: " + statusCode);

     method.releaseConnection();

     return method.getResponseBodyAsString();

Answer (score 0):

you should try to build client like this

```
    // Creating SSLContextBuilder object
    SSLContextBuilder SSLBuilder = SSLContexts.custom();

    // Loading the Keystore file
    File file = new File("mykeystore.jks");
    SSLBuilder = SSLBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(file, "changeit".toCharArray());

    // Building the SSLContext usiong the build() method
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLBuilder.build();

    // Creating SSLConnectionSocketFactory object
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConSocFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext,
            new NoopHostnameVerifier());

    // Creating HttpClientBuilder
    HttpClientBuilder clientbuilder = HttpClients.custom();

    // Setting the SSLConnectionSocketFactory
    clientbuilder = clientbuilder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslConSocFactory);

    // Building the CloseableHttpClient
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = clientbuilder.build();
```

Comment: Please let me know the which jar i have to used TIA

Comment: Go through this URL I hope it will work https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_httpclient/apache_httpclient_custom_ssl_context.htm

Comment: same your apache jar

Comment: I am using the above code but still i am getting the same error
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Plesae help me

Comment: With new code if you are still facing same issue check if your certificate is valid and it is imported correctly in JDK truststore (sometimes not added due to permisson issue) and third you should check you are using correct JDK(Where you imported certificates) using in code to connect https.

Comment: The problem is obviously not the server cert, it apparently is the lack of client cert. Your 'solution' not only can't solve the problem but it actively _prevents_ solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We normally use TrustStore to trust the 3rd party Server communication. In client and server communication over HTTPS protocol, the latter always lookup its keystore and present `the public key and certificate` to the prior. After that, the client looks up the `associated certificate in the truststore`. If the certificate or the Certificate Authorities shared by the calling server is not present in the client-side trust store(**By default, Java always bundles a truststore as cacerts and keeps it's in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security path**) then `SSLHandshakeException` will occur. To resolve the problem you have to add the trust store.

Default trusted Certificate Authorities can be listed using the command

```
keytool -list -keystore cacerts
```

you can add the trust store using the following command:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias certAlias -file certFile -keystore trustStoreFile
```

by default the trustStoreFile location is $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts. [you can refer here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19906-01/820-4916/geygn/index.html).

Comment: I am getting this in my logs
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]

Comment: have you tried to list the `cacerts`, because the log message says `Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication *** Certificate chain <Empty> *** *** ECDHClientKeyExchange`

Comment: Yes, I tired and there are 3 certificates
Using this keytool -list -v -keystore jssecacerts

Comment: were you able to find the server's certificate/ certificate authority information that you were intended to call in those 3 certificates?

Comment: Yes, This is print in the logs
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=ecw-test.mtn.co.ug, C=UG
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Jun 12 13:21:39 IST 2018,
               To: Thu Jun 11 13:21:39 IST 2020]
  Issuer: CN=m3_external_ca_test
  SerialNumber: [   -2afddf7d 2f077bc9

Comment: That's interesting, the expected trusted certificate present in the trust store but the client could not able to verify it, then the problem may be with the client certificate you are using with the `SSLBuilder`. please check the JKS file that you are using by the command  `keytool -list -v -keystore yourkeystore.jks` or using alias `keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks -alias expectedomain`

Comment: keytool -list -v -keystore jssecacerts -alias "ecw-test"

Alias name: ecw-test
Creation date: 11 Oct, 2019
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=ecw-test.mtn.co.ug, C=UG
Issuer: CN=m3_external_ca_test
Serial number: -2afddf7d2f077bc9
Valid from: Tue Jun 12 13:21:39 IST 2018 until: Thu Jun 11 13:21:39 IST 2020
]

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: your client is not SENDING a client certificate** as the server (definitely) requested, and apparently requires.

Note nothing is wrong with your *truststore* and changing your truststore or trustmanager is entirely irrelevant and useless. People who believe that all SSL/TLS problems are lack of validating (trusting) the server cert are like people who think that if the engine has been removed from your car it will still run great if you just put some gas (or petrol/essence/etc depending on country) in the tank.

From your debuglog:

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2), SHA512withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=m3_external_ca_test>
```

Server requested a client certificate, aka client auth(entication) aka 2-way or mutual authentication.

```
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
...
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange

[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
```

You didn't supply one (and the related signature to prove possession). Server aborts handshake, which in general can be for many reasons but the only likely one at this point is because you didn't supply the requested cert (and signature).

Go back near the top:

```
keyStore is : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
```

Notice this section does NOT say something like this, as it would for a usable client cert:

```
found key for : <alias>
chain [0] = [ <usually dozens of lines of data> ]
<usually chain[1], maybe chain[2] and more depending>
```

There are two quite different kinds of certificates: **a cert that identifies *you*** (or your device etc) and you want *others* to trust, for which you **must have the privatekey**, and a cert that identifies someone else which *you* trust, for which you should never have the privatekey. For client auth you need the first kind, and you don't have it. (Added note: In general for your own cert you *also* need one or sometimes more 'chain' or 'intermediate' cert(s), but in this case the debuglog makes clear you are using a dummy/test CA that doesn't use chain cert(s).)

Either you or somebody else prepared your `jssecacerts` wrong, or else it's the wrong file to use, since it is *intended* to contain certs for *others*, namely CAs, that you trust, which Java calls a truststore (although it's still in keystore *format*), and not certs for yourself, which is a true keystore.
The third cert listed as trusted, with `EMAILADDRESS=rchhabra@xpwallet.com`, looks like it was likely *intended* to be a client cert, but since you don't have the privatekey it can't be used as such. Either fix that file, or if you have the client cert WITH KEY in a different file, which would be a good and commonly used approach, use that different file instead.

Comment: I am the client and I am sending the request I have added the Trusted CA and SIgned CRT in my key store

Comment: Is your keystore jssecacerts or something else? The debuglog proves jssecacerts contains a _cert_ that looks reasonable but NOT THE PRIVATE KEY. If jssecacerts is your keystore, you 'added' to it incorrectly. You must have (add) the cert AND PRIVATE KEY as I said.

Comment: Is it necessary to import the private key in the keystore

Comment: To do client auth it is necessary to _have_ the privatekey _and_ cert chain in your keystore. If not already there, you must import them. Note you cannot import a privatekey by itself; if you have the privatekey _and_ cert(s) in a PKCS12 you can import them (together) to a JKS, although Java supports PKCS12 as a keystore so you also can just use it as-is.